# I am writing a program to find the anagrams from a list of words and output the anagrams in different lists but in an alphabetical order

Tags: python, list, alphabetical

```
some_list = ['bad', 'app', 'sad', 'mad', 'dab','pge', 'bda', 'ppa', 'das', 'dba']

new_list = []
from collections import OrderedDict
for ele in OrderedDict.fromkeys("".join(sorted(ele)) for ele in some_list):
    temp = []
    for s in some_list:
        if ele == ''.join(sorted(s)):
            temp.append(s)
    if len(temp) > 1:
        new_list.append(temp)

for i in new_list:
    i.sort()
    print(i)
```

---

The output is:

- `['bad', 'bda', 'dab', 'dba']`
- `['app', 'ppa']`
- `['das', 'sad']`

I want the output to be:

- `['app', 'ppa']`
- `['bad', 'bda', 'dab', 'dba']`
- `['das', 'sad']`

How do I change the code to get the right output?

Comment: duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30246225/create-lists-of-anagrams-from-a-list-of-words

Answer (score 4):

sort your `new_list` before printing using [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted)

```
for i in sorted(new_list):
    i.sort()
    print(i)
```

This will print your output as expected

Answer (score 1):

sort before you create the words:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
some_list.sort()
for ele in OrderedDict.fromkeys("".join(sorted(ele)) for ele in some_list):
   ...........
```

Comment: @BhargavRao, yep. Better to do it once at the start.